# How to set html Object(tag) value from code behind in vb.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net

I have following code `<object  data="/download/test.pdf" id="pdffile" type="application/pdf" width="900px" height="1200px" runat="server" >`

Here I want to set the **data** value from code behind in vb.net.

Comment: Why the C# tag then?

Comment: Could you explain more ? Do you want to get **/download/test.pdf** as output ? Or do you want to change **/download/test.pdf** to specific value and get the whole string as output ?

Comment: this data value should be dynamic. So that in the backend I can set data value as /download/Test2.pdf as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do.
Try this:
        **Dim str As String = "<object  data=""/download/test.pdf"" id=""pdffile"" type=""application/pdf"" width=""900px"" height=""1200px"" runat=""server"" >"
        Dim str2 As String = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, "data="".*?""", "data=""" & "NEW VALUE" & """")
        Console.WriteLine(str2)**

it will replace /download/test.pdf with the string **"NEW VALUE"**..
You can replace NEW VALUE with any value you want such as **/download/Test2.pdf**

Comment: Hi Youssef Thank you so much. I want to display on the page so, will it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used literal in aspx page and put html text in code behind page

`Literal1.Text = "<object width = '700px' height='800px' data='" + "/download/Invoice_PDF/" & Path.GetFileName(filepath) & ".pdf" + "'></Object>"`